# How can I create a code that will automatically apply shaders to the materials of the objects in the model?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code in c# that reads the materials of the tagged object and the renders it based on the shader that I want to use. I would like to know if there is a more easier way to this. In a model there are a lot of objects which have a lot of materials. It is very time consuming to create these many scripts and then run them on uniy3D. I want to create a script that would automatically find the materials of the objects in the model and apply shaders to them.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Put this on the parent GameObject and this should work, it finds all of the `Renderer`'s in the children of the game object and then assigns the shader.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AssignShadersToChildren : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Shader shader; // This should hold the Shader you want to use

    void Start() 
    {
        // We create a list that will hold all the renderers so we can then assign the shader
        List<Renderer> renderers = new List<Renderer>();
        renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();

        // For every Renderer in the list assign the materials shader to the shader
        foreach (Renderer r in renderers) {
            r.material.shader = shader;
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: This was written without a compiler so there is a chance this will not run.

If this answers you question be sure to accept this answer.

Comment: Hello Mythral, what if we want to use multiple shaders since each material is different. How can we do that? In my code I have tagged the object to find its materials. So when I run the script on the object in my model it tells the materials it is composed of. Then I apply the shaders to those materials by creating a if statement. My if statement looks for the material that I want to implement the shader to and then implements the shader. However, since there are multiple objects with various materials, it is difficult.